# Feasibility of Study in Cuba for U.S. Undergraduates

Tags: research-undergraduate, international, abroad

I'm assisting an undergraduate student with developing plans for summer 2014, and I'm considering the viability of study in Cuba.

Are there any U.S. users who have traveled to and studied in Cuba and can recommend a robust, reputable Cuba study program, ideally run by a U.S.-Cuba university partnership? Fields of interest to the student are political science, civil society, and history.

Of course, a Google search returns several options, but I'd still appreciate input or advice from fellow academia.SX users

Comment: According to [U.S. sanctions](http://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/sanctions/Programs/Documents/cuba.pdf), this will *only* be legal if the student receives course credit from the U.S. institution.  Hence I would start with your home institution; if it doesn't offer credit this project is probably a no-go.

Answer (score 3):

Ignoring the issue with obtaining a license to visit Cuba, I would say the feasibility of a US undergrad being able to study in Cuba is quite low. International study in a third world country is difficult and Cuba presents even more problems for US citizens. US credit and debit cards do not work in Cuba. You cannot wire money to Cuba, and you cannot legally exchange US dollars for Cuban currency. Staying in approved hotels and eating at approved restaurants is very expensive. Using the black market and finding less official housing and food is difficult and I think would be beyond a typical undergrad. I think anything related to political science would be a touchy subject. Finally, Cuba is very very hot in the summer, making getting anything done difficult.

Comment: Presumably an organized  study program will have solutions in place for most of these issues.